# Date of birth and expiration date, XX or XXI century?

Tags: passports

When we read machine-readable zone (MRZ) dates, we only see the last two digits in year. Is there a rule to establish when such date is 1900’s or 2000’s? It should exist something to check MRZ validators, but I don’t find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: this section of SE is for practical problems faced by travellers: if you are trying to design a system for passport validation it would fit better elsewhere in the network

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about the technical design of passports rather than their travel-related use

Comment: ICAO Doc 9303 does not seem to specify any way to encode the century.

Comment: Sorry if questiin seems off-topic, but I am not agree qith it... is a question related eith icao rules, not technical

Answer (score 0):

In Bulgaria for example, they are adding 40 to the month digits.

So if you are born after year 2000, say 15 september 2005 you will get:

**054915**

(yy-mm-dd) where 49 is 40 + 9th month = 49

But that is probably country dependant.

Comment: This would be against the specification. Are you sure it actually happens in the date-of-birth field in the MRZ?

Comment: I don't know about the MRZ code. I haven't seen a passport of a youngster :)